# Wordpress change or update post meta on post submit

Tags: php, wordpress, sql-update, meta

On a post submit action I try to change or at least to update the post_meta which will be added to the database. I setup the code down below but nothing seems to be updated. It's sure the vars inside the function are filled with the right data such as post_id, as the function is being executed.

```
function save_custom_meta( $post_id, $post, $update ) {

    update_post_meta( $post_id, '_variable_pricing', 1);

}
add_action('save_post', 'save_custom_meta', 10, 3);
```

Comment: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/127412/update-post-meta-whenever-custom-post-type-is-updated

Comment: Thank you. I found out, the problem is as follow. When I exit; directly after the update in my own function the data price variable is set to 1. When I remove the exit there must be another update because this makes it set back to 0.